# Can we do multiple replaces using replaceAll() in java

Tags: java, replaceall

The whole idea is to replace space followed by a comma (, ) or replace comma followed by a space ( ,) with only single comma(,). Can we do some thing like follows?

```
 strLine = strLine.replaceAll(", | ,",",");
```

Comment: *Can we do some thing like follows* - Yes. Give it a try. But thus won't be good for "1,2,   3,  4," for example.

Comment: You seem to have posted the answer already: `strLine = strLine.replaceAll(", | ,",",")` However, if you already tried that, but didn't get the expected result, please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Your replace will change `"a ,b, c , d  ,  e"` into `"a,b,c, d ,  e"`.

It may be better to use this form: `replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*",",")`.

This will produce `"a,b,c,d,e"`

`\\s` will match space, tabs and new line marks, `*` means that content before it can appear 0 or more times.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, because `replaceAll` first creates a `Pattern` before replacing, and if you look at the javadocs for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you can see that | has exactly the function you want to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
strLine = strLine .replaceAll("\\s?,\\s?",",");
```